# Python Causal Impact package error "attribute has no 'inferences' attribute"

Tags: python

I'm trying to use the causal impact package on a simple data set for sales in a store and I'm getting this error:

> AttributeError: 'CausalImpact' object has no attribute 'inferences'

This is what the data frame looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from causalimpact import CausalImpact


df

    Store   Order_Date  Sales
0   A       2020-12-01  1500
1   A       2020-12-02  2000
2   A       2020-12-03  1800
3   A       2020-12-04  1200
4   A       2020-12-05  1300
...
95  A       2021-03-27  2100
96  A       2021-03-28  2200
97  A       2021-03-29  1800
98  A       2021-03-30  1600
99  A       2021-03-31  1500 

pre_period = ['2020-12-01', '2021-01-17']
post_period = ['2021-01-18', '2021-03-31'] 
ci = CausalImpact(df['Sales'], pre_period, post_period)
ci.summary()
```

Comment: Can you add the code of class `CausalImpact` please or import line? And show the full error raise...

Comment: Hey Vincent - I just did! I've already provided the full error raise, nothing more appears than that.

Comment: That can't be true. Post everything from `Traceback (most recent call last):` to the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I was missing tensorflow on my system so once I did pip install tensorflow in the terminal everything started to work!